# 64 bit OS (Windows 7, 10 & Linux Ubuntu, Linux Mint) not booting with extra RAM but 32 bit OS (Windows 7) was fine with the same additional RAM

Tags: memory

As the topic suggests I am very curious to know the reason behind this problem if anyone could explain.

I previously had 32 bit Windows 7 running on Acer Aspire 4741 laptop (2010 model) which could boot and run well with 2 RAMs (4 GB + 2GB) though I could only use 2.89 GB max but the computer booted well every time with 2 RAMs. (( 2 GB RAM- 1066 mHz    4 GB RAM - 1600 mHz ))

Since 32 bit OS is far outdated I decided to upgrade to 64 bit and CPU was compatible with it but the computer did not boot with 2 RAMs. Sometimes errors and mostly the PC would be stuck in infinite boot loop.

Another interesting thing is that the BIOS recognizes both RAM but OS would never boot. PC only boots with 2 GB pre-installed RAM but not the other one. I tried all possible ways like exchanging the slots and trying 4 GB RAM alone in both slots but none of it worked.

I also updated BIOS to the latest version I could find in Acer website.

What could be the reason behind this problem?

Comment: Mixed memory modules (different size and/or different timing) are evil. I haven't found the specs for your laptop, so I cannot tell you which kind of memory modules you can put in the laptop. I think that 4GB is the maximum installable (2GB+2GB). Can you tell us CPU brand/model and the type of the original memory?

Comment: There may really be a problem with your RAM, but on a position above the 4Gb, which the 32bit OS couldn't reach.  Why not try a utility like memtest86+ ?

Answer (score 0):

Many 1st and 2nd generation Intel laptops are picky with RAM. (Even 3rd generation are picky sometimes and need 1.35 low voltage or 1.5 to boot).

That laptop supports a total of 8GB of RAM, but you need **low density RAM**.

Here is what low density RAM looks like. There are 8 chips on each side, so a total of 16 chips.

[image: Low density RAM]